# jQuery DataTable Inline Editing with Web-services

Tags: web-services, datatables, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to edit a jQuery DataTable using web-services in .Net. I'm able to load the data into the table okay and have the edit/delete/new buttons showing but can't seem to figure out how to Edit the table by passing the parameters to the UpdateTable WebMethod. The only documentation I've found is using PHP. Here is what I have:

```
var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

$(document).ready(function () {
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
    ajax: "../WebService1.asmx/UpdateTable",
    table: "#example",
    fields: [{
        label: "First name:",
        name: "FirstName"
    }, {
        label: "Last name:",
        name: "LastName"
    }
    ]
});
});
// Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
$('#example').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
editor.inline(this);
});

$.ajax({
url: '../WebService1.asmx/GetTable',
method: 'post',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
    $('#example').dataTable({

        dom: "Bfrtip",
        paging: true,
        sort: true,
        searching: true,
        scrollY: 200,
        data: data,
        columns: [
            {
                defaultContent: '',
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                orderable: false
            },
            { data: "FirstName" },
            { data: "LastName" }
        ]
        ,
        select: {
            style: 'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        buttons: [
            { extend: "create", editor: editor },
            { extend: "edit", editor: editor },
            { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
        ]
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Which jQuery plugin are you using for datatables?

Comment: I'm using Datatables.net

Comment: @Shane you found anything?